# How to list a specific data with *ngFor

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, ionic3, angularfire2

hi guys i am trying to make a simple friendrequests page with ionic3 and firebase

i succesfully listed usernames with ngfor. but i cannot list users FirstName from my data.

list html:

```
 <ion-item *ngFor="let friendrequest of friendRequestArray; let name of requesterName; let i = index" (click)="getFirstName(i)">
    <h2>{{friendrequest.$key}}</h2>
    <p> {{name}} </p>
  </ion-item>
```

constructor:

```
  friendRequestArray = [];
  requesterName =[];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,
    public alertCtrl: AlertController, private afDatabase: AngularFireDatabase, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) {

      this.myUid = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;

      this.afDatabase.list(`users/${this.myUid}/friendrequests/`).subscribe(data => {
        this.friendRequestArray = data;
        console.log(this.friendRequestArray);



      });


  }
```

now, usernames (friendrequest) works fine but {{name}} doesnt work because of specific parents. as you see there is a function for getting first name by click, it works fine and returns me the name of user as i want in console. but i want it in constructor, like username, for each request.

getting firstname function is this, and its not working in constructor;

```
      getFirstName(i) {

    this.afDatabase.object(`users/${this.friendRequestArray[i].$value}/profile`).subscribe(data => {

        this.requesterName = data.firstName;
        console.log(this.requesterName);
    });
  }
```

thanks for reading please assist me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you call it inside the constructor?

```
this.afDatabase.list(`users/${this.myUid}/friendrequests/`).subscribe(data =>{
    this.friendRequestArray = data;
    console.log(this.friendRequestArray);

    this.friendRequestArray.forEach((item, i) => {
       getFirstName(i);
    })


  });
```

Add one line to your getFirstName function to store firstName in friendRequestArray:

```
getFirstName(i) {

this.afDatabase.object(`users/${this.friendRequestArray[i].$value}/profile`).subscribe(data => {

    this.requesterName = data.firstName;
    console.log(this.requesterName);
    friendRequestArray[i]["firstName"] = data.firstName;
});
```

}

Now your html, can be:

```
<ion-item *ngFor="let friendrequest of friendRequestArray; let i = index">
    <h2>{{friendrequest.$key}}</h2>
    <p> {{friendrequest.firstName}} </p>
  </ion-item>
```